# configure selinux to prevent non-root users from accessing particular port

Tags: selinux

Can selinux be locked down to prevent non-root users to being able to access a particular port on linux?

e.g if I have a local web server, I would like to prevent non-root users from being able to access port 80 - so something like this command (or using a python script to connect to port 80) should fail for non-root users

> curl http://127.0.0.1/

but still allowing the command to succeed for root

Comment: I would probably reconsider my security model at that point...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SELinux: Limit httpd outbound connections by address and port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/366922/selinux-limit-httpd-outbound-connections-by-address-and-port)

Comment: @vidarlo - I don't think that answers my question (in full anyway). I don't see any mention of the user/user group in that. I would like root to be able to connect to a port, but not non-root users

Comment: for the love of god why